# R/3 installation sapinst giving database connection error

Tags: database, installation, oracle10g, database-connection, sap-r3

I am trying to install SAP R/3 ABAP, where databse instance is on one machine and central instance on different machine.
Database instance installation is finished but when trying to install central instance when sapinst tries to connect from Central Instance to database instance following error comes up

> WARNING    2009-05-02 07:53:08.490
> CJSlibModule::writeWarning_impl() Execution of the command "/usr/sap/E64/SYS/exe/run/startsap all DVEBMGS00 hpvm-202" finished
> with return code 6.
> Output: Database B11 must be started on remote
> server Log on to remote server and start database

So, I went to database server and verified and database was indeed running  (mounted and open).

```
ghoul3:e64adm 3> lsnrctl start
LSNRCTL for HPUX: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on 02-MAY-2009 07:18:11
Copyright (c) 1991, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started

ghoul3:e64adm 4> /oracle/B11/startdb
Trying to start B11 database ...
Log file: /home/e64adm/startdb.log
B11 database started
```

R3trans –d from adm user runs perfectly

```
ghoul3:e64adm 8> R3trans -d
This is R3trans version 6.14 (release 701 - 26.01.09 - 12:46:00).
unicode enabled version
R3trans finished (0000).
```

I tried with shutdown database, restarting both systems but to no avail.
I don’t want to initiate a re-install as its consumes long time and chances are that same error  crops up again, so better tackle it the first time itself.
Kindly advise how could we troubleshoot further or resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone faces the same issue, the problem lies with profile files, in profile files- Check for parameter named "SAPDBHOST" in DEFAULT.PFL.
Entry should be as

```
SAPDBHOST =
```

if it doesn't exit add hostname of the database instance.
Also, do check DEFAULT.PFL if the file name is "DEFAULT" only then rename it to DEFAULT.PFL.